# rails3 scope for count of children in has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

trying to do a scope in rails3.

```
:book has_many :chapters
```

I want scope :long to return books with > 10 chapters.

How best to structure this scope (without use of counter cache) ?

thanks!

Comment: Can you describe/ the post with the database you are using? I believe this is causing some confusion in the answers below

Answer (score 19):

This should get you going:

```
class Book
  scope :long, joins(:chapters).
                 select('books.id, count(chapters.id) as n_chapters').
                 group('books.id').
                 having('n_chapters > 10')
end
```

Does it help?

Comment: This is the way to go. Only problem I run into is that the count method doesn't really work as expected here. For instance, Book.long.count returns a hash with the count of chapters for each book, I think. You have to do Book.long.all.count. Not too bad I guess

Comment: That looks right but I'm getting an error: 'column "card_count" does not exist' (card_count is my n_chapters).  Everything by the `having` seems to work properly, and the card_count column is definitely populated when I run this directly in a SQL console...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's good practice to link other stackoverflow posts. But I have a similar problem to this post but it requires only certain attributes on the has_many objects. Would really appreciate the help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719184/rails-active-record-find-all-records-which-have-a-count-on-has-many-associati

Answer (score 8):

Ah - to answer my own question in the comment above, I had to put the count in the HAVING:

```rb
class Book
  scope :long, joins(:chapters).
    select('books.id').
    group('books.id').
    having('count(chapters.id) > 10')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In rails 4.0 this version works. 
You have to count() in the having clause. It seems that having clause doesn't see 'as n_chapters'.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to make a subquery. While the join is more correct (and possibly also leads to better performance), you may end up with strange results if you combine multiple scopes that try to do grouping. A subquery is much less intrusive. For this example, it would be something like:

```
class Book
  scope :with_chapters_count, -> {
    select('books.*').
    select('(select count(chapters.id) from chapters where chapters.book_id = books.id) as chapters_count')
  }
  scope :long, -> {
    with_chapters_count.where("chapters_count > 10")
  }
end
```