# Advanced Rails 3 scope with CROSS JOIN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, scope

I want a scope which returns me a list of (eg.) books they have chapters. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250451/rails3-scope-for-count-of-children-in-has-many-relationship/12252318#12252318).

It helped me to select books they have chapters. But if I want want to select those they have no chapters like:

```
    class Book
      scope :long, joins(:chapters).
        select('books.id, count(chapters.id) as n_chapters').
        group('books.id').
        having('n_chapters = 0')
    end
```

This scope returns me nothing. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `joins` leads to creating relation with all the combinations of book+chapter **that already have connection**. This is done vie `INNER JOIN` SQL-clause. You have to make `OUTER JOIN` if you want all the possible combinations to be created (including book+nullified chapter).

replace

```
joins(:chapters).
```

with

```
joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN chapters ON books.id=chapters.book_id').
```

**But** in this case consider using the `NOT IN` SQL-clause instead. Like here:

```
scope :long, lambda { where('id NOT IN (%s)' % Chapter.select(:book_id).to_sql) }
```

It is considerably smaller/faster and more readable/maintainable construction.

Comment: Great dude! Both of this solutions are working very well. I am so happy about this fast and competent help. I wish you a nice weekend ;)