# Rails - Active Record: Find all records which have a count on has_many association with certain attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

A user has many identities.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :identities
end

class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

An identity has an a `confirmed:boolean` column. I'd like to query all users that have an only ONE identity. This identity must also be confirmed false.

I've tried this

```
User.joins(:identities).group("users.id").having( 'count(user_id) = 1').where(identities: { confirmed: false })
```

But this returns users with one identity `confirmed:false` *but they could also have additional identities if they are confirmed true.* I only want users with only one identity confirmed:false and *no additional identities that are have confirmed attribute as true*.

I've also tried this but obviously it's slow and I'm looking for the right SQL to just do this in one query.

```
  def self.new_users
    users = User.joins(:identities).where(identities: { confirmed: false })
    users.select { |user| user.identities.count == 1 }
  end
```

Apologies upfront if this was already answered but I could not find a similar post.

Comment: Can the boolean column be null?  Or, is there a default set, so that it will always be `false` or `true`?  Also, what DBMS are you using (MySQL, PostgreSQL etc), and how is the boolean value stored in the database? (0/1, "f"/"t", etc)

Comment: Hey Max. Let's assume that the the column cannot be null so just false or true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use rails nested queries

```
User.joins(:identities).where(id: Identity.select(:user_id).unconfirmed).group("users.id").having( 'count(user_id) = 1')
```

And here's the SQL generated by the query

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
INNER JOIN "identities" ON "identities"."user_id" = "users"."id"
WHERE "users"."id" IN (SELECT "identities"."user_id" FROM "identities"  WHERE "identities"."confirmed" = 'f')
GROUP BY users.id HAVING count(user_id) = 1
```

**I still don't think this is the most efficient way.** While I'm able to generate only one SQL query (meaning only one network call to the db), I'm still have to do two scans: one scan on the USERS table and one scan on the IDENTITIES table. This can be optimized by indexing the `identities.confirmed` column but this still doesn't solve the two full scans problem.

For those who understand the query plan here it is:

```
     QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=32.96..33.09 rows=10 width=3149)
   Filter: (count(identities.user_id) = 1)
   ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=21.59..32.91 rows=10 width=3149)
         Hash Cond: (identities.user_id = identities_1.user_id)
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=10.45..21.61 rows=20 width=3149)
               Hash Cond: (identities.user_id = users.id)
               ->  Seq Scan on identities  (cost=0.00..10.70 rows=70 width=4)
               ->  Hash  (cost=10.20..10.20 rows=20 width=3145)
                     ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..10.20 rows=20 width=3145)
         ->  Hash  (cost=10.70..10.70 rows=35 width=4)
               ->  Seq Scan on identities identities_1  (cost=0.00..10.70 rows=35 width=4)
                     Filter: (NOT confirmed)
(12 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  def self.new_users
    joins(:identities).group("identities.user_id").having("count(identities.user_id) = 1").where(identities: {confirmed: false}).uniq
  end
```

Comment: Hey @Nermin. This does not seem to solve the problem. Calling uniq I believe is a uniqueness call on users, but all users returned should already be unique.

Answer (score 0):

I think `group_concat` may be the answer here, if you have the function in your DBMS.  (if not there may be an equivalent).  This will collect all the values for the field from the group into a comma-separated string.  We want ones where this string is equal to "false": ie, there's just one, and it's false (which i think is your requirement, it's a little unclear). .  I think this should work if we let Rails handle the translation of `false` into however the DB stores it.

```
User.joins(:identities).group("identities.user_id").having("group_concat(identities.confirmed) = ?", false)
```

EDIT - if your database stores false as `0` then the above will generate sql like `having group_concat(identities.confirmed) = 0`.  Because the result of the group_concat is a string, then it may (in some DBMS's) do a string-to-integer cast on the results before comparing it to 0, which will return lots of false positives if all the other strings cast to 0.  In that case you can try this:

```
User.joins(:identities).group("identities.user_id").having("group_concat(identities.confirmed) = '?'", false)
```

(note quotes around ?)

EDIT2 - postgres version.

I've not tried this but it looks like recent versions of postgres have a function `array_agg()` which does the same as mysql's `group_concat()`.  Because postgres stores true/false as `'t'/'f'` we shouldn't need to wrap the ? in quotes.  Try this:

```
User.joins(:identities).group("identities.user_id").having("array_agg(identities.confirmed) = ?", false)
```

Comment: Hey Max. So the one issue is that `User.joins(:identities).group("identities.user_id")` gives

`PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: Can you answer my comment above about what kind of DBMS you are using please?

Comment: I think were getting closer but I'm getting an error ```PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information``` because identities.confirmed is not an array type I believe.